# Laravel 8: Weird missing required parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a form action like this:

```
action="{{ route('verify.order', $order->id) }}"
```

And on **web.php**:

```
Route::post(
            'order/verify/{id}' , 
            [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\OrderController::class, 'verify']
           )->name('verify.order');
```

Also I call the method on Controller like this:

```
public function verify(Request $request, $id)
```

But as soon as I try to load the Blade, I get this error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: verify.order]` [Missing
> parameter: id]. (View: order.blade.php)

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: does $order->id has value.It might be empty .so check once

Comment: Why not use the route method as usual, and as documented, with an array as the second argument?

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes it has value

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't get what you mean by usual way

Comment: can you post full blade code

Comment: As written in the answer: usually, all route parameters must be given as an **array**, such that Laravel can map the named elements of that array to the named parameters of the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might pass the route parameter(s) as array:

```
action="{{ route('verify.order', ['id' => $order->id ]) }}"
```